# Identifying single outliers using `diff()`

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a rather simple outlier check as proposed in [Zahumenský (2004)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228826920_Guidelines_on_Quality_Control_Procedures_for_Data_from_Automatic_Weather_Stations): Guidelines on Quality Control Procedures for Data from Automatic Weather Stations.

According to the article, when checking for the maximum allowed variability of measurements, values differing from the prior one by more than a specific limit fail the check and should be flagged as doubtful. That is what I tried with e.g. air temperature values using a critical delta of 3 K per time step.

What I tried so far:

```r
set.seed(42)
ta <- rnorm(60, mean = 12, sd = 0.2) |> round(1)

# generate outliers
ta[15] <- 39
ta[45] <- -19

# carry out step test
ta_delta <- c(NA, diff(ta))
ta_delta
#>  [1]    NA  -0.4   0.2   0.0   0.0  -0.1   0.3  -0.3   0.4  -0.4   0.3   0.2
#> [13]  -0.8   0.2  27.1 -26.9  -0.2  -0.4   0.0   0.8  -0.4  -0.3   0.4   0.2
#> [25]   0.2  -0.5   0.0  -0.3   0.5  -0.2   0.2   0.0   0.1  -0.3   0.2  -0.4
#> [37]   0.1   0.0  -0.3   0.5   0.0  -0.1   0.3  -0.3 -30.9  31.1  -0.3   0.5
#> [49]  -0.4   0.2   0.0  -0.3   0.5  -0.2  -0.1   0.1   0.0  -0.1  -0.6   0.7

length(ta_delta)
#> [1] 60

which(abs(ta_delta) > 3)
#> [1] 15 16 45 46
```

What I would need in the end is a logical vector of the same length as `ta` (check), flagging the outliers only with `TRUE` at indices 15 and 45.

Currently, I'm not identifying the outliers only but also the subsequent value, so my idea was to narrow down `abs(ta_delta) > 3` to individual segments holding `c(TRUE, TRUE)` and just pick the global index of the first `TRUE`, hopefully resulting in the desired output. But I'm also pretty sure there are probably some functions resp. ideas how to tackle this which I'm missing.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would say, strictly, speaking, the definition you're using *"values differing from the prior one by more than a specific limit fail the check and should be flagged as doubtful"* both the outlier you introduce and the following one should be flagged. You create the sequence `..., 11.7,  11.9,  39.0,  12.1, ...` and 39.0 differs from 11.9 by more than your threshold, and it's also true that 12.1 differs from 39 by more than your threshold. If you want a more refined result, you'll need a more refined check.

Comment: perhaps `which(diff(abs(ta_delta) > 3)==1)+1` or `c(F,(diff(abs(ta_delta) > 3)==1))`

Comment: Since your "found" indices are always in pairs,  modify your last command to something like `foo <- which (abs(ta_delta) > 3);  bar <- foo[seq(1,length(foo),by=2))`

Comment: @GregorThomas Strictly speaking, you're absolutely right. And still, using your subset, to me it would feel wrong to flag both values since this would also eventually lead to both "outliers" to be removed later on. So yeah, I'd definitely need a more refined check in the end, but I wanted to get started with reference values from literature first.

Comment: @Waldi Looks great, thank you very much! Have not thought about another `diff()` applied on the logical vector... :)

Comment: You have correctly implememted the simple reference from literature and you don't like the result. Maybe it's time to refine already. There are plenty of other outlier detection algorithms and [even R packages to implement them](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tsoutliers/).

Comment: @GregorThomas Hmm, I rather thought of tweaking the result a little since I'm not sure if this really was the original intention of the author. However, thanks a lot for another reference! Not sure how good of a fit `forecast::tsoutliers()` will be in the end, since decomposition might not work with every parameter, but I'll definitely give it a try! Already refining... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
log_vec <- diff(abs(ta_delta) > 3) == -1  # Or < 0
print(log_vec)
# [1]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [55] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

which(log_vec)
# [1] 16 46
```

You can pad with `FALSE` as needed and correct any leading `NA`s.

The code makes sense as a (form of) numerical second order differentiation and finding a local maximum.

**Edit:**

More direct "numerical differention" would be:

```
which(diff(abs(diff(ta))) < -3)
# [1] 15 45
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this seems to be exactly the part I was missing in the end... And with a minor modification (not much different from the padding proposed, I guess) I get the result I was looking for with `which(log_vec) - 1`.

Comment: Glad I could help. I had read your need as the logical vector and not the list of indicies (otherwise I would have subtracted the 1 :)). Anyway, you could also do something like:
`which(diff(abs(diff(ta))) < -3)` which would be more like real double differentiation. However, I cannot off the top of my see what if threshold of 3 should translated here. My intuition says it stays the same. I've added an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably be a bit more circumspect than using `diff` here. For example, there may be consecutive outliers. An iterative approach that incorporates the previous states would be more robust, and you can encapsulate the logic in a function to make it easy to re-use, or to tweak your threshold for calling a measurement an outlier.

```r
find_outliers <- function(vec, max_diff = 3) {
  
  if(length(na.omit(vec)) < 2) return(numeric())
  
  for(i in seq_along(vec)[-1]) {
    last_valid <- tail(na.omit(head(vec, i - 1)), 1)
    if(abs(vec[i] - last_valid) > max_diff) {
      vec[i] <- NA
    }
  }
  which(is.na(vec))
}
```

Testing on your example, we have:

```r
find_outliers(ta)
#> [1] 15 45
```

But we can also be assured that two or more consecutive outliers will be identified:

```r
ta[16] <- 38

find_outliers(ta)
#> [1] 15 16 45
```

Comment: Wow, this is really great - and I'm completely with you when it comes to robustness. This is definitely a scenario where `diff()` would be failing and your approach seems not to! As it was already said in the comments to the question, I'd need a more refined check and not rely on diff only, of course. So this one goes straight to my list for further testing with real data. However, and maybe I messed up here. I feel like I should accept the answer relating to the original question the most (i.e. diff)... But your approach totally wins beyond that, thank you very much again!

Comment: @dimfalk there is no pressure on you to accept _any_ answer to your question. You have accepted one that you felt best answered your question, and that's entirely appropriate.